# Youtube mini-series about people suddenly disappearing

Tags: story-identification

These are the details I remember:

- It was about suddenly **almost everyone disappears**.
- The whole story is centered around this guy who is trying to find his family after everything happened.
- During the journey, he starts finding what happened and why people disappeared.
- Episodes on **Youtube, about 3-4 minutes each**.
- The format was kind of like a drawn comic-sketch based scenes, with little animations.
- It was narrated from the point of view of the protagonist.

OK, that's all I can remember. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Afterworld](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afterworld_%28web_series%29)

Not the be confused with the similarly named Russian MMO.